# Pagination in DynamoDB using batch methods

Tags: spring-boot, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I have 2 tables in DynamoDB, namely products and sellers.

```
Seller: sellerId (partitionKey) (No sort key available)
Products: productId (partitionKey) and sellerId (sortKey)
```

I want to develop an API in spring boot where I pass in productId as the input and expect a paginated list of sellers who sell the corresponding products.
I will have to first fetch a list of products using the productId and then use the sellerId in them to fetch seller data. I am currently thinking of using mapper.query for the first call and mapper.batchLoad for the second call.
How can I paginate my results?

Comment: Why to have 2 tables, you can use 1 table to store both with Single Table Design approach. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/creating-a-single-table-design-with-amazon-dynamodb/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of maintaining 2 tables, you can use **single-table design** with DynamoDB.

Below is how you can model your table in DynamoDB.

### Way 1

[image]

### Way 2 (Recommended)

You can also use `string set` to store sellers. `String Set` ensures unique strings in the list. This will save you to create extra rows to store product & seller mapping.

[image]

With this way, you can get seller-ids along with product query, and then you can make a batch-read request to get details of sellers.

### For Pagination

- Either you can use `do/while` loop, and continue query until `LastEvaluatedKey` becomes null.
- Or return `LastEvaluatedKey` to client to get next set of data.